# When compiling with XeTeX, why do some letters become stretched and warped?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, compiling

When compiling with XeTeX using the Helvetica font, some letters become verticaly stretched (e.g: f and capital letters), some become generally bigger (e.g: j), brackets become slightly unaligned from the text, and it seems slightly blurrier, and less readable. I cant quite fully explain why but it just doesn't look as good.

You have to open the image bellow and zoom in to see what I mean.

[image]

This is a shame because I want to use the psvectorian package, which is only compatible with XeTeX.

Is it because of something in my pre-amble which is causing XeTeX to look bad, or is XeTeX just not as nice looking as PDFLatex?

My Pre-amble:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % This gives us the pound sign
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[english]{babel} %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{authblk} % multiple authors
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz} % For Latex flowcharts
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,backgrounds}
\usepackage{booktabs} %nicer tables
\usepackage{caption} %nicer captions
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}%to insert code extracts
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum} %random text filler
\usepackage{float}%exact placement of floats
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %make contents page of pdf hyperlinks. Load at end of preamble

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %change the font
\linespread{1.5}
```

I'm using ShareLaTeX to write the document.

Comment: with xetex you wouldn't normally use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} ` and you definitely shouldn't use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` although hard to say more without any example code.

Comment: I just looked at the documentation for `psvectorian` which seems to be in French so I may have missed something but I don't see any dependence on xetex, it seems to use pstricks but latex/dvips should work fine.

Comment: Latex works, but pdfLatex doesn't. Or at least it doesn't on sharelatex.com or overleaf.

Comment: yes that's expected for pstricks